# Firebase build presence: Unsafe call of an `any` typed value

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-realtime-database

I admit that firebase documentation seems to hard for newbies.

I already followed how [firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/presence) setup about build presence but I got this error in `userStatusFirestoreRef`.

```
userStatusFirestoreRef.set is not a function
```

This is my code I don't know what I missed since using firebase API is really hard to find examples tho.

in my firebase.ts

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import {
  getFirestore,
  collection,
  getDocs,
  addDoc,
  setDoc,
  doc,
  getDoc,
  Timestamp,
  serverTimestamp,
  onSnapshot,
  query,
  orderBy,
  where,
  QueryConstraint,
  limit,
  startAfter,
} from "firebase/firestore";

import {
  getAuth,
  RecaptchaVerifier,
  signInWithCredential,
  signInWithPhoneNumber,
  signOut,
  onAuthStateChanged,
  ConfirmationResult,
} from "firebase/auth";

import {
  onDisconnect,
  ref as dbRef,
  getDatabase,
  onValue,
} from "firebase/database";

import { getStorage, ref, uploadBytes, getDownloadURL } from "firebase/storage";
import firebaseConfig from "./configs/firebaseConfig";

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const db = getFirestore(app);
const auth = getAuth();
const storage = getStorage();
const firebaseDb = getDatabase(app);

export {
  db,
  auth,
  doc,
  collection,
  getDocs,
  getDoc,
  addDoc,
  setDoc,
  RecaptchaVerifier,
  signInWithPhoneNumber,
  signOut,
  onAuthStateChanged,
  signInWithCredential,
  Timestamp,
  serverTimestamp,
  storage,
  ref,
  uploadBytes,
  getDownloadURL,
  onSnapshot,
  query,
  orderBy,
  where,
  limit,
  startAfter,
  onDisconnect,
  dbRef,
  firebaseDb,
  onValue,
};

export type { ConfirmationResult, QueryConstraint };



import {
  auth,
  serverTimestamp,
  onDisconnect,
  dbRef,
  firebaseDb,
  onValue,
} from "../firebase";

if (uid) {
      const userStatusFirestoreRef = dbRef(firebaseDb, `status/${uid}`);
      const isOfflineForDatabase = {
        state: "offline",
        last_changed: serverTimestamp(),
      };

      const isOnlineForDatabase = {
        state: "online",
        last_changed: serverTimestamp(),
      };

      const connectedRef = dbRef(firebaseDb, ".info/connected");
      onValue(connectedRef, (snapshot) => {
        if (snapshot.val() == false) {
          userStatusFirestoreRef.set(isOfflineForDatabase); // error here
          return;
        }

        onDisconnect(userStatusFirestoreRef)
          .set(isOfflineForDatabase)
          .then(() => {
            userStatusFirestoreRef.set(isOnlineForDatabase); // error here
          });
      });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two syntax variants of the Firebase JavaScript APIs:

- The original namespaced syntax, which follows a format of `object.method(...)` access.
- The newer modular syntax introduced in SDK version 9, which follows a more functional `method(object, ...)` syntax.

The latter syntax allow build tools to remove unused code from the SDK during the build process, so that you end up with a much smaller bundle.

---

While you can pick either syntax, you can't mix and match the two syntaxes in a single code block - which is what your problem stems from.

This it your current code:

```
onValue(connectedRef, (snapshot) => {
  if (snapshot.val() == false) {
    userStatusFirestoreRef.set(isOfflineForDatabase); // error here
    return;
  }

  onDisconnect(userStatusFirestoreRef)
    .set(isOfflineForDatabase)
    .then(() => {
      userStatusFirestoreRef.set(isOnlineForDatabase); // error here
    });
});
```

Here the `onValue` is a modular API call, while `userStatusFirestoreRef.set(isOfflineForDatabase)` is using the namespaced syntax.

The simplest way to fix the problem, is to only use modular calls:

```
onValue(connectedRef, (snapshot) => {
  if (snapshot.val() == false) {
    set(userStatusFirestoreRef, isOfflineForDatabase); // 
    return;
  }

  onDisconnect(userStatusFirestoreRef)
    .set(isOfflineForDatabase)
    .then(() => {
      set(userStatusFirestoreRef, isOnlineForDatabase); // 
    });
});
```

Also see the Firebase documentation on [writing values to the database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#web-modular-api_1) with both the modular and the namespaced API.